# CUDA debugging in NSight Eclipse in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, cuda

I would like to debug some CUDA code in Linux. However, I came across an error that pertains to X11 not being able to share the GPU with the NSight visual debugger using Eclipse Nsight. 
However today I came across this.

> **3.4.2. Single-GPU Debugging with the Desktop Manager Running**
>
> CUDA-GDB can be used to debug CUDA applications on the same GPU that
>   is running the desktop GUI.
>
> Note: This is a BETA feature available on Linux and supports devices
>   with SM3.5 compute capability. There are two ways to enable this
>   functionality:
>
> Use the following command: set cuda software_preemption on Export the
>   following environment variable: CUDA_DEBUGGER_SOFTWARE_PREEMPTION=1
>   Either of the options above will activate software preemption. These
>   options must be set prior to running the application. When the GPU
>   hits a breakpoint or any other event that would normally cause the GPU
>   to freeze, CUDA-GDB releases the GPU for use by the desktop or other
>   applications. This enables CUDA-GDB to debug a CUDA application on the
>   same GPU that is running the desktop GUI, and also enables debugging
>   of multiple CUDA applications context-switching on the same GPU.
>
> Note: The options listed above are ignored for GPUs with less than
>   SM3.5 compute capability.

From here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-gdb/index.html#single-gpu-debugging-with-desktop-manager-running

**Question:**

So before I ask my project manager for a new compute SM3.5 compute capability graphics card, can anyone verify that this is working?

Does it work well?

My platform is **Centos 7.0**, Intel 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the card, anyway in CentOS 7 it works well. There's some slowdown when it goes into the kernel, but it does what I wanted it to. I can see the variable values inside the kernel.

One thing though, as of today 18/2/2016, I cannot press "stop" when debugging kernels. It hangs the whole system. Oh well, it did say it is a beta feature.